# Bootstrap header overlap main Body div for responsive web design

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap in ASP.net MVC 5 web application for responsive web design. My issue is I need to put image in header which is about width of 180px. but when i put image in header, it doesn't pushing down main body (next div) but overlap the information in body. I am struggling ... need help

http://getbootstrap.com/

```
<!--*************************** Header ***********************************-->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             <!--@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Home", "Dashboard", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })-->
             <!--<a href="@Url.Action("Home", "Dashboard")" class="logo"></a>-->
            <img src="~/ImagesAndIcons/Images/LCM.jpg" style="max-width:15%;height:auto;" />
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!--end header-->

<div class="body-content">

    <!--*************************** Main Body ***********************************-->

    <div id="body_main_wrapper">
        <!--Functions Panel Wrapper (left-side)-->
        <div id="Functions_Panel_Wrapper">
            <a>functions lists.....</a>
        </div>

        <!--Functions Page Wrapper (right-side)-->
        <div class="Function_Page_Wrapper">
            @RenderBody()
        </div> <!--end Function_Page_Wrapper-->

    </div> <!--end body_main_wrapper-->

        <!--*************************** Footer ***********************************-->
        <div class="footer_wrapper">
            <footer>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="footer_Title_Wrapper">
                        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                    </div> <!--end footer_Title_Wrapper-->
                </div> <!--end container-->
            </footer>
        </div><!--end footer_wrapper-->
    </div> <!--end body-content-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a fixed header. When you're using the fixed header type, you have to pad the top of the body element to push the content down far enough to accommodate the header. By default, Bootstrap takes care of that for you, but if you increase the height of the header, then you have to adjust `padding-top` accordingly on the body element.

Comment: i have add code above, yes i am using fixed type and trying to squeeze image in it

Comment: The code doesn't really help. You just need to determine how high the header is (an easy way is to inspect with Chrome's developer tools or Firebug in Firefox), and then add a new `padding-top` value for `body` in your stylesheet to accommodate that height value.

Comment: the idea is fine but is not responding to increase and decrease in size of page view

Answer (score -2):

Add following code after end of the header

```html
<div class="row visible-sm" style="height:90px;"></div>
```